# Get methods from class when using a prototype

Tags: javascript

I am writing some code to extend `Object`, and I would like to loop over the methods within the object. When I output the value of `this.constructor`, I see the methods that I would like (in the example below I see `test`). However, when I loop over the methods using a for, it only displays the method `getType`. How can I get just the methods of `class A`?

```js
Object.prototype.getType = function () {
  // Outputs correct class and methods
  console.log(this.constructor)

  for (let i in this.constructor) {
    // Outputs wrong methods
    console.log(i)
  }
}

class A {
  test() {console.log('hello')}
}

new A().getType()
```

Comment: for (let i in this) instead of for (let i in this.constructor)

Comment: @Codebeat In latest FF, same result.

Comment: what is the value of this.constructor.name in Object.getType()? I think it is object. It is better to not 'extend' the object object and create self defined class as base.

Comment: Note that "[*Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types)" has a distinct meaning that is not "class". E.g Array is type "object". So "getType" should probably be "getClass", but ECMAScript doesn't really have classes either (despite the class syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Properties can be enumerable – visited by for…in loops – or not. When you define a method in a `class`, the default is non-enumerable. (`Object.prototype.getType`, on the other hand, is enumerable because that’s the default when you create a property by assignment.)
2. You’re looping over properties of what the object claims is its constructor, but non-static methods like `test` are properties of the constructor’s `prototype` property (`A.prototype`), not the constructor itself (`A.test` isn’t a thing).

You can find non-enumerable properties with the [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) function:

```
Object.prototype.getType = function () {
  for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.constructor.prototype)) {
    console.log(name)
  }
}
```

Note that this only includes *own properties* – properties directly on the object – so if you want to include inherited methods, you’ll have to go up the prototype chain.

```
function* getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
  do {
    yield* Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
  } while (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))
}

Object.prototype.getType = function () {
  for (let name of getAllPropertyNames(this.constructor.prototype)) {
    console.log(name)
  }
}
```

And if you want to include properties directly on the object, you’ll have to start there (and hope `this.constructor.prototype` is `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)`).

```
Object.prototype.getType = function () {
  for (let name of getAllPropertyNames(this)) {
    console.log(name)
  }
}
```

Also, don’t extend `Object.prototype`. *Especially* not with enumerable properties. Management is not responsible for dependencies that break in mysterious ways when you do this.

Comment: 3rd problem: the *constructor* property may not point to the actual constructor. 4th problem: *constructor.protoype* may not point to the prototype used when the object was constructed. 5th problem: there maybe multiple constructors. So yes, *Object.getPrototypeOf* up the tree is the way to go (but also resolving duplicate properties). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but one way to do this is via a call to `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`, passing the object instances `__proto__` reference.

```js
Object.prototype.getType = function () {

  /*
  // Outputs correct class and methods
  console.log(this.constructor)

  for (let i in this.constructor) {
    // Outputs wrong methods
    console.log(i)
  }
  */

  for(let j of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.__proto__)
  .filter(method => method !== 'constructor')) 
  {
    // Outputs properties of prototype, without constructor method
    console.log(j);
  }
  
}

class A {
  test() {console.log('hello')}
}

new A().getType()
```

Answer (score 1):

The *getType* name seems inappropriate, what you're looking for are properties, so *getAllProperties* seems a better name.

As others have said, you need to go up the `[[Prototype]]` chain for a number of reasons:

1. Objects inherit from their constructor's prototype, not the constructor itself
2. The *constructor* property may not point to the actual constructor
3. The *constructor.prototype* may not be the one used to create the object
4. There may be multiple constructors
5. Inherited properties may be duplicated, you need to get just the "closest" one

The `[[Prototype]]` chain ends in *null*, which is the prototype for Object.prototype and is the top of all prototype hierarchies. The function should also remove duplicates, which can occur on each prototype (e.g. *constructor*, and *length* is pretty common).

```js
function getAllProperties(obj) {
  // Recursively get properties up [[Prototype]] chain
  function loop(obj) {
    let props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
    let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    
    // Stop at null
    if (proto !== null) {
      return props.concat(loop(proto));
    }
    return props;
  }
  
  let allProps = loop(obj);
  
  // Remove duplicates
  return allProps.filter((prop, i) => !allProps.includes(prop, i+1));
}

console.log(getAllProperties('a'))
```

If you want just methods, then filter as you go for `typeof x == 'function'`:

```js
function getAllMethods(obj) {
  // Recursively get properties up [[Prototype]] chain
  function loop(obj) {
    // Get all properties, filter for functions
    let props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).filter((prop, i, props) => typeof props[prop] == 'function');
    let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);

    // Stop at null
    if (proto !== null) {
      return props.concat(loop(proto));
    }
    return props;
  }

  let allMethods = loop(obj);

  // Remove duplicates
  return allMethods.filter((prop, i) => !allMethods.includes(prop, i + 1));
}

console.log(getAllMethods('a'))
```